# Mouse appearance upside down, but physical position of mouse is correct

Tags: mouse, screen, tablet, orientation

So I reinstalled in my tablet Ubuntu 18.04 again, but this time it was upside down, so I ran `xrandr` to correct the screen but it not only changed the screen orientation but also the mouse, if I click with the mouse on the right top corner, it assumes that I’m clicking in the lower left corner.

Comment: The answer from here might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328248/screen-detection-and-mouse-reverse-x-y-axis-kali-linux

Comment: Well , now that i see the problem is not the mouse , its the screen , the screen its upside down but the mouse pointer is right and works right , just the "projection of the screen" , this is a similar case https://devrant.com/rants/1152705/screen-is-viewed-as-inverted-but-the-cursor-is-still-right-thank-you-ubuntu-but